# Putting an ampersand (&) in a webpage's path (via WordPress Yoast) can be problematic?

Tags: seo, wordpress, path, character-set, yoast

I consider putting an ampersand (&) in a webpage's path (via WordPress Yoast).

I have a webpage with the `h1` of "Questions and answers" and I'd like the webpage path to be just q&a (like `example.com/q&a`).

If I'll write in Yoast `q&a` as path, can this be problematic?